# How to change TextArea placeholder text using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am trying to change pleaceholder text when document loads, i tried following code but it's not working,

**HTML:**

```
    <textarea id="nf-field-195" name="nf-field-195" class="ninja-forms-field nf-element" 
placeholder="Please provide a brief description of your facility" required=""></textarea>
```

JS:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){

 $('#nf-field-195').attr('placeholder','Some New Text 1');
});
</script>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8dwpsucf/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```js
selectedTextarea = $('#nf-field-195')[0];
selectedTextarea.placeholder = "Placeholder text";
```

Comment: Thanks, can you please share jsfiddle as it's not working for me

Comment: Your code works also well. You forgot to choose jquery as library.

Comment: Just select a Jquery Version from the select option above your JS Code in Fiddle and it works.

Comment: can you please see why it's not working here: http://mv-daycare.com/fiverr/

Comment: Test it. Works in the console on your page.

Comment: In which file you put the code....can not find a script.js file or something else where you put the code into.

Comment: i am using header and footer plugin, if you search "Some New Text 1" in view page source you'll see it

Comment: Maybe you have a failure in including the jquery file at your wordpress site. I think this is the problem.